# nodejs NET api bug? Seeking flawless reconnect fix

Tags: node.js, api, sockets, reconnect

I think there may be an issue with the Nodejs v5.3.0 NET api. I am wanting to rely on the socket.remoteAddress field flipping to undefined when the socket is destroyed.

- **socket.remoteAddress**
  The string representation of the remote IP address. For example, '74.125.127.100' or '2001:4860:a005::68'. Value **may** be undefined if the socket is destroyed (for example, if the client disconnected).

The challenge here is the **may** language above (bold added for emphasis).

Context: I'm writing a MEaN app that uses sockets to communicate with a remote deviec. The connection is often disconnected and I need to seamlessly reconnect it before use. I have the various functions needed to transmit call connect() before they want to transmit to ensure the connection is live.

---

UPDATED WITH FIX per mscdex:

```
if ( !client.readable )
    client.connect(PORT,HOST);
else
    logger.debug('Attempt to reconnect on an active connection. Ignored.');
```

client.readable provides immediate status on the network connection even if the intent is to write to the connection. client.writable is buffered and thus 'lies' (is overly optimistic) about the connection being present or able to be established.

---

The below is working code:

```
var logger = require('winston');
var net = require('net');
var client = new net.Socket();

var init = function() {
    logger.info('Calling connect now...' );
    connect();
};
exports.init = init;

var output = function(action, id) {
    connect();
    //Transmit stuff  here
};
exports.output = output;

var connect = function() {
    // Check to see if remoteAddress is undefined. If so, then connect
    logger.debug('Test if connection is active: ' + client.remoteAddress);
    if ( typeof (client.remoteAddress) == 'undefined' ) {
        client.connect( 2101, '10.10.10.4', function() {
            logger.info('Connection now open');
        });
    }
    else {
        logger.debug('Attempting reconnect on active connection. Ignore: ' + client.remoteAddress);
    }
};

// This events, as expected, when the VPN is connected and data is received.
client.on('data', function() {
    logger.debug('Data incoming');
});

// This events, as expected, when the VPN drops
client.on('error', function() {
    logger.debug('Connection error so destroy() the client');
    client.destroy();
    // I *was* expecting destroy() to make typeof (client.remoteAddress) = 'undefined'. It does not.
});
```

Here's what the resultant log looks like

```
info: Calling connect now...
debug: Test if connection is active: undefined
info: Connection now open
debug: Data incoming
debug: Data incoming

debug: Test if connection is active: 10.10.10.4
debug: Attempting reconnect on active connection. Ignore: 10.10.10.4
POST /elk/output 200 18.122 ms - 2

debug: Data incoming
```

I disconnected the VPN

```
debug: Test if connection is active: 10.10.10.4
debug: Attempting reconnect on active connection. Ignore: 10.10.10.4
POST /elk/output 200 1.546 ms - 2
debug: Connection error so destroy() the client
```

Now, given the client.destroy(); call, I'd expect client.remoteAddress to become undefined per document but it is not.

```
debug: Test if connection is active: 10.10.10.4
debug: Attempting reconnect on active connection. Ignore: 10.10.10.4
debug: Connection error so destroy() the client
POST /elk/output 200 1.063 ms - 2
```

Thoughts?

Thanks

Comment: Why not clear `client.remoteAddress` manually after you called `destroy()`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could also check if the TCP stream is readable or not by checking `client.readable`.

Comment: Hi mscdex, client.writable seemed like a great idea. I just tried and it say 'true' while it is **waiting** on a connection (which seems wrong). Once the connection times out, it reverts to false again. I'll try it with a shorter timeout tomorrow to see if that works better. Thanks.

Comment: Ah yeah, I think it's because you can technically "write" by buffering in memory before the connection is made. Briefly looking at net.js, it looks like `socket.readable` may be a better alternative.

Comment: Well done mscdex! socket.readable is 'instantaneous' in its signalling. Perfect fix.

Answer (score 1):

Don't use remote ip to detect if the remote connection has been disconnected. Instead, subscribe to the [`close`](https://nodejs.org/dist/latest-v5.x/docs/api/net.html#net_event_close_1) event (and depending on the use case, maybe the [`end`](https://nodejs.org/dist/latest-v5.x/docs/api/net.html#net_event_end) event as well):

```
client.on('close',function(){
    // client has been disconnected.
    connect();
});

client.on('end',function(){
    // client wants to disconnect.
    connect();
});
```

To really close the socket you can set the `close` (and `end`) handlers to do nothing:

```
client.on('close',function(){});
client.destroy();
```

Comment: Thanks Slebetman but I'm not sure this will work. Not all closures are initiated from the server. e.g.: When the VPN is cut, the remote server does not do an orderly shutdown and so I don't see any CLOSE or END events.

Comment: @DanPl: If you don't see a close event then you won't see IP address going undefined. It is the v8 engine that sets the IP address and it sets it depending on weather or not it detects a disconnection and it will trigger a close event if it detects a disconnection. If there is no close event then there is no other way to detect this. You can test this out. 1. kill -9 the remote process. 2. pull out your ethernet cable (WIFI doesn't quite work the same way but it will disconnect once the OS detects the router is down after a long timeout) 3. pull the plug on the remote server

Comment: In my experience you will receive a close event in all cases except the 3rd point. Note that you will still receive a close event if you shut down the remote server. The only way I've managed to simulate an unclosed connection is to pull the plug literally (or if the remote is a laptop remove the battery without being connected to mains power)